# deploy a react app which uses an index.html as the entry point

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, github-pages

I have the following code in my package.json - which is usually sufficient to deploy a react app to github pages.  This app is slightly different as I use an index.html file in the public folder - does anyone know of a solution to deploy this to github pages?

https://github.com/simharuk2021/reduxcart/tree/main/public

I have already tried playing about with the url but makes no difference, I just get the standard react app readme page displayed post deployment.

````
  "name": "reduxcart",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.10",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "homepage": "https://simharuk2021.github.io/reduxcart/public/"
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNSsY.png
````

Comment: I guess you have wrong setup in your repository, could you share a screenshot of this project github pages setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using main branch for deploying, github pages require you to use gh-pages branch, it should be created automatically after you use command: `npm run deploy`. Here's the reference: https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-react-apps-github-pages/